# Default constructor significance in this scenario

Tags: java

I have three classes like below

```
public abstract class Parent {
    public void parentCallerMethod() {
        getMethod(helperMethod());
    }
    public abstract void getMethod(String test);

    public String helperMethod() {
        System.out.println("inside parent helperMethod");
        return "inside parent helperMethod";
    }
}
```

2nd class

```
public class Child extends Parent {
    @Override
    public void getMethod(String test) {
        System.out.println("Inside child getMEthod....");
    }
}
```

Final Class that calls the parent class method

```
public class FinalClass {
    private void testMethod() {
        new Child().parentCallerMethod();
    }
}
```

My question is what does `new Child().parentCallerMethod();` do? What's `new Child()`. Why is that I won't be able to do `Child.parentCallerMethod()`

Is it similar to doing `Child child = new Child();`

PS : The post title may be wrong. If it's wrong I'll change it based on the answer.

Comment: Isnt problem that `parentCallerMethod` isnt static ? Then you cant do `Child.parentCallerMethod()`

Comment: @Ziker : Yes if I make that static then I will be able to do `Child.parentCallerMethod()` however I'd like to understand what `new Child().parentCallerMethod();` does?

Comment: Sounds like your fairly new to coding. new Child() is creating a new instance of the Class Child. You need to have an object to get to the parent method. If you want you could change your methods and or classes static to get access to the method and not create an instance of the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new Child().parentCallerMethod()` is the same as:

```
Child child = new Child();
child.parentCallerMethod();
```

but without conserving the instance variable.

It will call the parent method, since `Child` doesn't override it. You are not able to call `Child.parentCallerMethod()` because this method is not `static` (class method).

Answer (score 0):

`new Child().parentCallerMethod();` creates a new instance of your Child class, and then calls the method on the instance of your Child class.

`Child.parentCallerMethod();` would be calling a `static` method of the class Child. Which does not exist, so that's why you are not able to call it.

Answer (score 0):

`new Child()` creates an instance of the child class. `object.something()` calls method `something` on the result of the expression `object`. So if you substitute `new Child()` for `object` and `parentCallerMethod` for `something`, you get `new Child().parentCallerMethod()`, which creates a new `Child` object and calls the `parentCallerMethod` method on it.

Answer (score 0):

The code `new Child().parentCallerMethod()` creates a new Child object and calls the method on that object.

The call `Child.parentCallerMethod()` would be a *static* method call, but `parentCallerMethod` is not declared static. A static method means that the method belongs to the class and cannot access any members of a child object as there is no object.

The `new Child()` call creates a `Child` object which could contain fields. In your case, `Child` doesn't actually contain any fields, so there is nothing to access.

If it did, your methods would be able to access data in the object.

Comment: Is it similar to doing Child child = new Child();

Comment: Yes. Pretty much exactly the same, except you are not actually assigning the reference of the Child object to anything, so once the method call finishes the Child object will probably no longer be accessible.